# Creating a temporary table of dates mysteriously "appends" the data to the temp table over and over?

Tags: mysql

I need to cross join with a table of dates so I used:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myDates AS (

SELECT 

CAST((SYSDATE()+INTERVAL (H+T+U) DAY) AS date) d

FROM ( SELECT 0 H
    UNION ALL SELECT 100 UNION ALL SELECT 200 UNION ALL SELECT 300
  ) H CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 T
    UNION ALL SELECT  10 UNION ALL SELECT  20 UNION ALL SELECT  30
    UNION ALL SELECT  40 UNION ALL SELECT  50 UNION ALL SELECT  60
    UNION ALL SELECT  70 UNION ALL SELECT  80 UNION ALL SELECT  90
  ) T CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 U
    UNION ALL SELECT   1 UNION ALL SELECT   2 UNION ALL SELECT   3
    UNION ALL SELECT   4 UNION ALL SELECT   5 UNION ALL SELECT   6
    UNION ALL SELECT   7 UNION ALL SELECT   8 UNION ALL SELECT   9
  ) U

WHERE
  (SYSDATE()+INTERVAL (H+T+U) DAY) <= (SYSDATE()+INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

);
```

But for some reason this keeps appending dates to the temp table `myDates`. Why is this happening?

**EDIT #1**: I'm unable to reproduce this on my other server. In the problem server, I had this snippet running when I was working on my big query. Could that have been why?

**EDIT #2**: In the problem server when I run this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myDates AS (

SELECT 

CAST((SYSDATE()+INTERVAL (H+T+U) DAY) AS date) d

FROM ( SELECT 0 H
    UNION ALL SELECT 100 UNION ALL SELECT 200 UNION ALL SELECT 300
  ) H CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 T
    UNION ALL SELECT  10 UNION ALL SELECT  20 UNION ALL SELECT  30
    UNION ALL SELECT  40 UNION ALL SELECT  50 UNION ALL SELECT  60
    UNION ALL SELECT  70 UNION ALL SELECT  80 UNION ALL SELECT  90
  ) T CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 U
    UNION ALL SELECT   1 UNION ALL SELECT   2 UNION ALL SELECT   3
    UNION ALL SELECT   4 UNION ALL SELECT   5 UNION ALL SELECT   6
    UNION ALL SELECT   7 UNION ALL SELECT   8 UNION ALL SELECT   9
  ) U

WHERE
  (SYSDATE()+INTERVAL (H+T+U) DAY) <= (SYSDATE()+INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myDates;
```

This time running it I get `8738`, the next `9104`. It keeps appending it. Whaaat?

Answer (score 0):

So it is appending 366 each time you run the query.
Have you tried
DROP TABLE myDates;
Once you have finished with the table? This isn't a solution, but may work as a work around.

Also you could try repairing the database including all the tables.
mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases from command line sql, to see if this helps.

Comment: Yes. It's appending 366 everytime. I will temporarily try DROP TABLE or use a new table name, but I just want to find out why this happens.

Comment: Sounds fairly glitchy. Have you changed user permissions on that database server?